# How to run multiple instances of command-line tool in bash script? + user input for script

Tags: bash, macos, webcam

I am trying to launch multiple instances of `imagesnap` simultaneously from a single bash script on a Mac. Also, it would be great to give (some of) the arguments by user input when running the script.

I have 4 webcams connected, and want to take series of images from each camera with a given interval. Being an absolute beginner with bash scripts, I don't know where to start searching. I have tested that 4 instances of imagesnap works nicely when running them manually from Terminal, but that's about it.

To summarise I'm looking to make a bash script that:

- run multiple instances of imagesnap.
- has user input for some of the arguments for imagesnap.
- ideally start all the imagesnap instances at (almost) the same time.

**--EDIT--**

After thinking about this I have a vague idea of how this script could be organised using the ability to take interval images with `imagesnap -t x.xx`:

- Run multiple scripts from within the main script

*or*

- Use subshells to run multiple instances of `imagesnap`
- Start each sub script or subshell in parallel if possible.
- Since each instance of `imagesnap` will run until terminated it would be great if they could all be stopped with a single command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following quick hack (saved as `run-periodically.sh`) might do the right thing:

```
#!/bin/bash

interval=5
start=$(date +%s)

while true; do
    # run jobs in the background
    for i in 1 2 3 4; do
        "$@" &
    done
    # wait for all background jobs to finish
    wait
    # figure out how long we have to sleep
    end=$(date +%s)
    delta=$((start + interval - end))
    # if it's positive sleep for this amount of time
    if [ $delta -gt 0 ]; then
        sleep $delta || exit
    fi
    start=$((start + interval))
done
```

if you put this script somewhere appropriate and make it executable, you can run it like:

```
run-periodically.sh imagesnap arg1 arg2
```

but while testing, I ran with:

```
sh run-periodically.sh sh -c "date; sleep 2"
```

which will cause four copies of "start a shell that displays the date then waits a couple of seconds" to be run in parallel every `interval` seconds.  if you want to run different things in the different jobs, then you might want to put them into this script explicitly or maybe another script which this one calls…

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Though it would work nicely, I will try to do this a bit differently. The imagesnap has the ability to take shots with an interval using `imagesnap -t x.xx` . I will see if I can figure out how to use subshells or separate scripts for each instance of imagesnap.